# Is there a way to display 2 decimal places instead of automatically rounding?

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple calculator in c# and and everything works well until I try dividing numbers that should give decimal places. How to display 2 decimal places in these cases?

I've tried putting #.## after .ToString.

```
{label1.Text = (divide / Convert.ToInt64(label1.Text)).ToString("#.##");}
```

I expect the output of 5/4 to be 1.25, but it is 1.

Comment: What is the type of `divide`?  If it's an integer type then you're doing integer division.

Comment: That's because integers don't contain decimals. You would have to do the same but convert into a float or decimal data type

Comment: You need to use float as your type, Convert to float instead and make divide too float

Comment: If you are doing a calculator, you may be happier with the `decimal` type (compared to `float` or `decimal`).  It's more exact.  The `float` and (especially) `decimal` types have a wider range, but less accuracy.  It would likely be worth it for you to spend some time understanding the difference between integral types, traditional floating point types and `decimal` if you are writing a calculator.

Comment: Also read up on integer division and modulus.  If you divide integer 7 by integer 4 (7/4), you will get 1.  However, if you evaluate the modulus of those two numbers (7%4), you will find out that the remainder is 3.

Answer (score 0):

convert the number to float instead of int,

```
{label1.Text = ((float)divide / float.Parse(label1.Text)).ToString("n2");}
```